# Can not read image file by using opencv with windows

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to run the first example of opencv with Visual Studio 2022, which is given on opencv's doc page, but it always return the WARN: `can't open/read file: check file path/integrity`

I have tried absolute path, relative path, or move the .bmp file to my working directory where exe file stays, read another png file, but none of these works. How can I make it work? There is no strange letter in my image path.

I put the code here:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>



using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << " Usage: " << argv[0] << " ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if ( !std::filesystem::exists(argv[1]) ) {
        std::cout<<"file doesnt exist"<<std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "found file at:" << argv[1] << std::endl;
    }
    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file
    if (image.empty()) // Check for invalid input
    {
        std::cout << "can not open image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image); // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

what I run: `ImgCompare20231127.exe lux.png` the png file is under the directory where .exe file is

And the output is:

```
found file at:.\lux.png
[ WARN:0@0.014] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_(''): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
can not open image
```

I'm using Chinese version windows10 and vs2022, will the character encoding matter? (but I check the file as you see it exists)

Comment: Tried forward slash instead of backslash?

Comment: Yes I also tried that, but didn't work

Comment: First check if that file exists using [std::filesystem::exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists).

Comment: Try to check the permission of the image file, and change it to readable

Comment: And here's the obligatory [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I checked the file permission, it can be read, and it exists...

Comment: The part of the warning that says `cv::findDecoder imread_('')` is rather suspect. It's produced by [this code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp#L248) and there should be a filename between those single quotes.

Comment: Is this happening in debug mode or release mode, or both? Are you linking the appropriate OpenCV library (debug in debug mode, release in release mode?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by changing the character encoding method from `UNICODE` to `MBCS` (Multi-Byte Character Set) in Visual Studio 2022 settings.

Since my Windows 10 system is using Chinese as the system language, which is using `cp936` encoding method, but Visual Studio 2022 was using Unicode for character encoding, this caused unreadable characters while running programs.